# Query is taking too much time

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to take your ideas regarding the below query:

```
select a.expense_code, a.expense_date, a.expense_supplier_code, b.supplier_name, a.expense_discount, a.expense_payment_method, a.expense_payment_transfer_to, a.expense_advance, a.expense_status,
                            sum(c.expense_item_buy_price * c.expense_item_quantity) , d.account_name, a.expense_counter, a.expense_type, a.expense_saving_type, a.expense_payment_transfer_from
                            from expense_data a, supplier_data b, expense_item c, tree_data d
                            where a.expense_supplier_code = b.supplier_code and a.expense_payment_transfer_to= d.account_code
                            and a.expense_counter = c.expense_counter
                            and a.expense_date between '2013-01-01' and '2014-01-01' and a.expense_status = 0 or a.expense_status = 2 group by (a.expense_counter);
```

This query is taking so much time even though in the expense_data table, there are four indices:

```
1- Expense_code. 
2- expense_user_id
3- expense_supplier_code
4- expense_payment_transfer_from
```

I do not know why it takes so much time is it because of two much join or is it because too much indeces. Can you please suggest?

Comment: Have you taken a look at operator precedence? And has higher priority than or. At the end, you write `a.expense_status = 0 or a.expense_status = 2`. I think that should either be in parentheses or you should change it to `a.expense_status in (0, 2)`, unless you actually mean that any row with status 2 should be returned, regardless of other conditions.

Comment: Run 'EXPLAIN EXTENDED '+ YourQuery Code; and post results to your question above, otherwise we have no idea of table size, type, way indices are being used to execute the query etc.

Comment: Don't forget to use the Execution Plan.

Answer (score 2):

Could be that your where clause contains a logical error.
Look at the last line (last OR condition):

```
where 
  ....
  and a.expense_counter = c.expense_counter 
  and a.expense_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' 
  and a.expense_status = 0 
  or a.expense_status = 2
```

That means "take records between dates etc. AND with status 0, OR **take all records with status 2**"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When somebody's answer proves helpful to you, please accept it by clicking on the green outline checkmark. It's also polite to upvote any answers you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

To speed things up, you might want to try to make a combined index on a combination of the columns you join on. That index might be more useful than the four separate indexes you have now, although you can still keep those. Apart from those four fields, you may even want to experiment by adding `status` and/or `expense_data` to the index.

Comment: He needs to post explain extended and a describe for the tables, even covering indices are pointless and wastes of space/time spent blocking if they are ordered improperly or have type/length variance.

Answer (score 0):

Recoding it to make the joins clearer (and removing that massive join where if expense status was all tables were joined) gives:-

```
SELECT a.expense_code, 
    a.expense_date, 
    a.expense_supplier_code, 
    b.supplier_name, 
    a.expense_discount, 
    a.expense_payment_method, 
    a.expense_payment_transfer_to, 
    a.expense_advance, 
    a.expense_status,
    SUM(c.expense_item_buy_price * c.expense_item_quantity) , 
    d.account_name, 
    a.expense_counter, 
    a.expense_type, 
    a.expense_saving_type, 
    a.expense_payment_transfer_from
FROM expense_data a, 
INNER JOIN supplier_data b ON a.expense_supplier_code = b.supplier_code
INNER JOIN expense_item c ON a.expense_counter = c.expense_counter
INNER JOIN tree_data d ON a.expense_payment_transfer_to= d.account_code
WHERE a.expense_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' 
AND a.expense_status = 0 OR a.expense_status = 2 
GROUP BY (a.expense_counter);
```

Looking at that it is important that you have an index on supplier_code on the supplier_data table, an index on expense_counter on the expense_item table and an index on account_code on the tree_data table.

I suspect you don't really want to return items with an expense status of 0 and an expense date in that range, with any record of expense status 2 irrespective of date so the following might be what you want:-

```
SELECT a.expense_code, 
    a.expense_date, 
    a.expense_supplier_code, 
    b.supplier_name, 
    a.expense_discount, 
    a.expense_payment_method, 
    a.expense_payment_transfer_to, 
    a.expense_advance, 
    a.expense_status,
    SUM(c.expense_item_buy_price * c.expense_item_quantity) , 
    d.account_name, 
    a.expense_counter, 
    a.expense_type, 
    a.expense_saving_type, 
    a.expense_payment_transfer_from
FROM expense_data a, 
INNER JOIN supplier_data b ON a.expense_supplier_code = b.supplier_code
INNER JOIN expense_item c ON a.expense_counter = c.expense_counter
INNER JOIN tree_data d ON a.expense_payment_transfer_to= d.account_code
WHERE a.expense_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' 
AND a.expense_status IN (0, 2)
GROUP BY (a.expense_counter);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put OR condition in brackets:

```
SELECT a.expense_code, 
   a.expense_date, 
   a.expense_supplier_code, 
   b.supplier_name, 
   a.expense_discount, 
   a.expense_payment_method, 
   a.expense_payment_transfer_to, 
   a.expense_advance, 
   a.expense_status, 
   SUM(c.expense_item_buy_price * c.expense_item_quantity), 
   d.account_name, 
   a.expense_counter, 
   a.expense_type, 
   a.expense_saving_type, 
   a.expense_payment_transfer_from 
FROM expense_data a, 
   supplier_data b, 
   expense_item c, 
   tree_data d 
WHERE a.expense_supplier_code = b.supplier_code 
   AND a.expense_payment_transfer_to = d.account_code 
   AND a.expense_counter = c.expense_counter 
   AND a.expense_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' 
   AND (a.expense_status = 0 OR a.expense_status = 2)
GROUP BY a.expense_counter;
```

Comment: That is a change in functionality which changes behaviour rather than speed things up (although it accidentally might).

Comment: It will speed things up - by removal of this HUGE cartesian join AxBxCxD! That's deffinitely an error, not intentional condition.

Comment: Yes, but speeding things up by changing the results is usually not desired, unless it is actually a bug, which is just a guess at the moment. You should at least mention that you changed the behaviour of the query.

Comment: That's an obvious logical error my friend.
And fixing it shurely will change the behaviour of the query - by making it work.